# Is a variable like "int nameofvariable" an object?

Tags: objective-c

My question is as it is in the title. However, if it isn't an object, how can it then be maintained in `NSMutableArray` as an object? Because `NSMutableArray` is only for storing objects or am I wrong? :)

Answer (score 2):

Primitive types, like `int`, must be wrapped in an object before it can be added to a collection class like `NSMutableArray`. Try this:

```
int nameOfVariable = 42;
NSMutableArray *array = ... // the initialized array
[array addObject:@(nameOfVariable)];
```

The last line is modern syntax that essentially means:

```
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:nameOfVariable]];
```

Later on, when you need to get the value back, you do:

```
int someVariable = [array[someIndex] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not an object and you can therefore not put it in an `NSArray`. You have to wrap it in an `NSNumber`, which is an object and can be put in an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

An `int` is a primitive type inherited from C (examples of other primitive types are `char`, `long`, `float`, etc.). These are not Objective-C objects. To add a primitive type to an `NSMutableArray` or any other Objective-C collection, you must wrap them in an object. For number types like `int`, you would use [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html) as follows:

```
int i = 1;
[array addObject:@(i)]; // @(i) is equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithInt:i]
```